# Rounds off numbers from 1 - 10, 000 including negatives

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel

I was trying to replicate Python's internal round() function. 
The program asks for a number, converts it into a float (catches the value error if present) and gets the absolute value of the float (to handle negative numbers).

```
def rounder(): 
    number = input("Give me a number to round off!: \n")
    #Makes sure you enter a valid number
    try:
        floater = float(number)
        absol = abs(floater)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number.\n")
        starter()

    if absol < 10 and absol > 0: #Works for both 0.6 and 1.6 | Because 0.6 is too small for 1 and will return the rounding while 1.6 % == 0.6 also
        rounding = absol % 1
        if rounding >= 0.5: #If more than 0.5
            absol += 1 #Increment It
            temp =(int(absol)) #Convert back to integer

            if floater < 0: #Negative check
                print(-temp)
            else:
                print(temp)

        elif rounding < 0.5:
            temp = (int(absol))

            if floater < 0: #Negative check
                print(-temp)
            else:
                print(temp)

    elif absol < 100 and absol > 10: #use %10
        rounding = absol % 10
        rounding2 = rounding % 1
        if rounding2 >= 0.5: #If more than 0.5
            absol += 1 #Increment It
            temp = (int(absol)) #Convert back to integer

        if floater < 0: #Negative check
            print(-temp)
        else:
            print(temp)

    elif rounding2 < 0.5:
        temp = (int(absol))

        if floater < 0: #Negative check
            print(-temp)
        else:
            print(temp)
    rounder()

def starter():
    print("Compatible from 0.1 - 9999.9") 
    rounder()       

starter()
```

It keeps on going like that until `if absol < 10000 and absol > 1000` . Also the number of modulo operations (%) it goes through increases.

The ranges are hard-coded so it can only handle numbers from 1 - 10 000. I could manually increase the limitation if I wanted but I would have to keep doing that until infinity.

1. Does anyone have any idea on how to get beyond this limitation?
2. Can my code be refined? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Keep all answers beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### min < value < max

Python makes this kind of conditions really easy:

> ```
> if absol < 10 and absol > 0:
> ```

Like this:

```
if 0 < absol < 10:
```

#### Don't repeat yourself

Instead of this:

```
    if floater < 0: #Negative check
        print(-temp)
    else:
        print(temp)

    # ...

    if floater < 0: #Negative check
        print(-temp)
    else:
        print(temp)
```

Create a helper function:

```
def abs(num):
    if num < 0:
        return -num
    return num
```

Comment: I have implemented both suggestions, thank you!